# Change properties of a css class based on selected theme (selected in the ui) in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular8, theming

I have an Angular 8 application whereas the user can switch between two different themes in the ui. I have a class on a div where I would like the background-color to be different in each theme. But I cannot make this happen.

Perhaps there is someone here who have done something similar before?

Myapp.component.html

```
<div class="ui-layout">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="wrapper">


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Myapp.component.scss

```
.card {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.black-blue-theme {
    .card { 
    background-color: #424242 !important;
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.componentCssClass = 'light-indigo-theme';
        themes.current('generic.light');
        this.setupOverlayContainer();
        this.subscribeToObservableFooter();

    }

    setupOverlayContainer() {
        const containerElement = this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement();
        if (containerElement) {
            const classList = this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList;
            const toRemove = Array.from(classList).filter((item: string) =>
                item.includes('-theme'),
            );
            classList.remove(...toRemove);
            classList.add(this.componentCssClass);
        }
    }

    changeTheme(type: string) {
        this.componentCssClass = type;
        if (type === 'black-blue-theme') {
            themes.current('generic.dark');
        } else {
            themes.current('generic.light');
        }
        this.setupOverlayContainer();
    }
```

Comment: can you show more about your `app.component.ts` ? You would also need a `[ngClass]` or a `[class]` in the html.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post. Yeah I figured I need an [ngClass], not sure how to set that up tho. Tried [ngClass]="{dark-theme : dark-blue-theme}" ..with .dark-theme as a class in the css file. Didn't work tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Just needed to edit app.component.scss and NOT Myapp.component.scss

app.component.scss

```
.black-blue-theme {
    .card { 
    background-color: #424242 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two themes, one of them should be used by default. Ok, let's make something like that.

**app.component.ts**

```
currentTheme: string = 'generic.dark';

changeTheme(type: string) {
    this.currentTheme = type;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="ui-layout" [ngClass]="currentTheme">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="wrapper">


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```